# What are these shadows Black Panther is fighting in this episode of "Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes"?

Tags: marvel, avengers-earth-mightiest-heroes

By the end of the first season of *Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes*, the heroes got teleported into the other 8 realms (they were on Midgard).

Black Panther was teleported into some kind of dark location with tombs and dead trees. Shortly after, he was pursued by some kind of shadow creatures:

[image: Black Panther is running away from a horde of shadows with glowing yellow eyes, on what seem to be a rather desolate place with dead trees and a green sky]

Nothing is said about these creatures nor the location. Who or what were they?

Comment: That is [Svartalfheim](https://avengersearthsmightiestheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Svartalfheim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [a user-edited wiki](https://avengersearthsmightiestheroes.fandom.com/wiki/Svartalfheim), but

> As Loki had conquered all of the realms except for Midgard, Svartalfheim was among them. In Svartelfheim, Black Panther had been pulled into there and was chased by the Dark Elves' tortured souls after examing the bones of the dead elves. After a long chase, he finally found his way out through the well which leds to Alfheim where he bumped into Hawkeye and Faradei.

Comment: The Marvel Database [agrees with this](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Svartalfheim#Avengers:_Earth.27s_Mightiest_Heroes_.28Earth-8096.29) but again it is only fan edited. I haven't seen the show but from the description of it I can't imagine it's wrong.

Comment: Also in [the transcript](https://transcripts.fandom.com/wiki/The_Fall_of_Asgard), also user-inputted.

Comment: The place where he was transported, [Svartelfheim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svartálfar), is “the home of dark elves”, according to Wikipedia. It’s ought to be them!